# Unable to assign parent folder when creating file. File not found error

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api

My service account is able to read files and folders without any issue. When I attempt to create a new folder or file within an existing folder using a fileId as a parent, the parent always comes back 'File not found.' I've queried the drive for available folders and the folder I'm trying to use as a parent appears.

The scope I'm using is 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive' which I'm assuming is global.

```
exports.listDrives = async function listDrives(drive) {
    const res = await drive.drives.list()
    if (res.data) {
        return {success: true, data: res.data}
    } else {
        return {success: false, message: 'Error listing drives.'}
    }
}

exports.listFiles = async function listFiles(drive) {
    const res = await drive.files.list({driveId: '0AE58XC8YRuIHUk9PVA', includeItemsFromAllDrives: true, corpora: 'drive', supportsAllDrives: 'true'})
    if (res.data) {
        return {success: true, data: res.data}
    } else {
        return {success: false, message: 'Error requesting file list.'}
    }
}

exports.createFolder = async function createFolder(drive, projectName) {

    const resource = {
        name: Date.now().toString(),
        mimeType: 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
        parents: ['1cmEWI_iRQ0R2QHZE1lhbIB9KcbtTts1C']
        // parent contained in listed drive
    }

    const res = await drive.files.create({
        resource
    }).catch(e => {
        console.log('error creating file', e.errors)
    })

    if (res.data) {
        console.log(res.data)
        return {success: true, data: res.data}
    } else {
        return {success: false, message: 'Error creating folder.'}
    }
}



Output I'm receiving: 

{ kind: 'drive#driveList',
  drives:
   [ { kind: 'drive#drive',
       id: '0AHau-J3SwHpjUk9PVA',
       name: 'FlashSparkTest' },
     { kind: 'drive#drive',
       id: '0AE58XC8YRuIHUk9PVA',
       name: 'TestTwo' } ] }
{ kind: 'drive#fileList',
  incompleteSearch: false,
  files:
   [ { kind: 'drive#file',
       id: '1cmEWI_iRQ0R2QHZE1lhbIB9KcbtTts1C',
       name: 'test2 testFolder',
       mimeType: 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
       teamDriveId: '0AE58XC8YRuIHUk9PVA',
       driveId: '0AE58XC8YRuIHUk9PVA' } ] }
error creating file [ { domain: 'global',
    reason: 'notFound',
    message: 'File not found: 1cmEWI_iRQ0R2QHZE1lhbIB9KcbtTts1C.',
    locationType: 'parameter',
    location: 'fileId' } ]
```

Comment: Where can you see the folder of `1cmEWI_iRQ0R2QHZE1lhbIB9KcbtTts1C`?

Comment: It appears when I list folders, and also in the UI under my drive account. I can see all folders in my drive account when listing. I just can't write to any of them. Instead, a new fileId for a new folder is created.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your script, the service account is used. And it seems that your script try to create the folder in your Google Drive. I think that the reason of your issue is this. The service account is different from your account. So when the service account is used, the file is put to the Google Drive of the service account. And this drive cannot be seen with the browser. By this, such error occurs. If you want to create the folder in the Google Drive of your account. Please use OAuth2. If this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tanaike, but I need the connection to Google to be made on the backend, hence the service account. The documentation I've read states that as long as a drive or folder is shared with the service account email address, the service account should be able to access, read from and write to the shared folder/drive. Right now I'm able to read, but not write.

Comment: Thank you for replying. When a folder in Google Drive of your account is shared with the service account as writer, new folder and files can be created in the folder using the service account. So can you confirm whether the folder is shared with the service account as the writer again? And also please confirm the folder ID again.

Comment: I'm able to confirm by running a 'list' request on the folder ID of the folder in my personal drive. I get a reply with the correct contents. I've found some other references about formatting of data in the parent[] parameter when creating new folders/files. When I use an array of strings (only 1 parent so 1 string) I get the file not found error. When I use a key-value pair of {id: 'id#'} I don't receive the error, but the randomly generate parent folder ID is created within the service worker drive and not my personal drive. I've also added 'supportsTeamDrives: true' to my resource object.

Comment: I couldn't notice that you had not tried to create the folder in the Drive of the Google Drive of your account. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by switching to JWT auth. If anybody runs into this issue in the future, this is an excellent tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/embed/gGSJpp6_ax0